# Trying to access to array in view return Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2, I'm trying to execute a stored procedure and display the result in a view using a foreach loop. When I run my app I get the following error message:

> Trying to get property of non-object

If I use return or dump I get the following result:

[image: Result]

Here is my controller code:

```
public function VentasPorSucursal() {
    $values = [1, 25, 2, "NULL", "2018-08-10", "2018-08-10", "NULL", "NULL"];

    $data['data'] = DB::select('SP_RPT_VENTAS2 ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?', $values);

    //dump($data);
    return view('reportes.index')->with('data', $data);
}
```

And this is my index.blade.php

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th>Folio</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Sucursal</th>
                <th>Vendedor</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Unidad</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Pzaz x Pq</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>Total Pzaz. Vendidas</th>
            </thead>
            @foreach ($data as $result)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $data->Folio }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Fecha }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Sucursal }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Vendedor }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Cantidad }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Unidad }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Descripcion }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->PzasxPq }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Precio }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->Total }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $data->TotalPzasVendidas }}</td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    {{$data->render()}}
```

Looking for an answer I found that using '->' it's for an array and maybe my code is returning the result as an object and I need to use '[]' but I don't know exactly how can I do it.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your dump result. The data array you are passing to view contains a `data` key which contains all of your objects returned from query. So you can loop through data variable data objects like this:

```
@foreach ($data['data'] as $result)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $result->Folio }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Fecha }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Sucursal }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Vendedor }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Cantidad }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Unidad }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Descripcion }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->PzasxPq }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Precio }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->Total }}</td>
   <td>{{ $result->TotalPzasVendidas }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is  in `foreach` loop which i reset is below and secondly
If the  return result is an array it can be access like below.

```
  @foreach ($data as $result)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $result["Folio"]}}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Fecha"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Sucursal"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Vendedor"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Cantidad"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Unidad"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Descripcion"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["PzasxPq"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Precio"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["Total"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $result["TotalPzasVendidas"] }}</td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach
```

Comment: FYI: If the field is missing is easier to use `array_get('Cantidad')`

Comment: what do  you mean by field is missing.Sorry if not get what you want please clarify.

Comment: @jycr753 
array_get()
The array_get function retrieves a value from a deeply nested array using "dot" notation:

$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

$price = array_get($array, 'products.desk.price');
Reference:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers

Comment: I can't test your code but data from array can't be access that's way have a look at my answer.

Comment: Your `@foreach` is off; you want to loop `$data["data"]`, not just `$data`. Also, `$data["data"]` is an array containing `stdClass` objects, so `$result` wouldn't be an array and `[]` syntax wouldn't work. Need to use `->` accessor.